# Dynamically loading an external file in Expo using OTA update

Tags: react-native, expo

In a detached Expo project with Expokit SDK, I would like to load an external file (say Tensorflow model) on demand using OTA update feature.

It would help with 2 things. 
A) The user need not download the model file during installation 
B) We can update the model file anytime.

I am just wondering would it be possible to use the Expo's Assets & LoadAsync functions to achieve this use-case. Any ideas would be greatly helpful.

Comment: For iOS I could add a resource file pointing to ../assets folder. If we find an optimal solution for Android, it would help to do ML in Edge devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use the [Expo filesystem API](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/). We are maintaining the files in s3 and downloading them into the FileSystem.documentDirectory on a specific user action. We check the version required by the code on the app start and update the model file accordingly. By this, we are able to load the file on demand and reduce the app size.